# Does a low-discrepancy sequence get arbitrarily closer to a given point with more terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

Here I am particularly interested in two-dimensional sequences in $X = [0, 1]^2$. My question is given a point $p \in X$, does a low-discrepancy sequence $S = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N\}$ get arbitrarily closer to $p$ with more terms? Or in other words, is it true that $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \min_{x \in S} \Vert p - x \Vert_2 = 0$ ?

I would like some explanations why the above is true or not true? In case it is not true (the above property $\neq$ low discrepancy), what is the above property called and are there examples of such sequences satisfying the property? In case it is true, how can I relate that to the definition of discrepancy of a sequence?

---

[EDIT 1] Added a definition of discrepancy of a sequence.

Define $X = [0, 1]^d$ as a space over which to generate sequences, $\mathcal{R}$ a range space (collection of subsets of $X$) and $R \in \mathcal{R}$.

Discrepancy $D$ of a sequence $P = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N\}$ is defined as how far from being *uniform* a sequence $P$ is, i.e.

$$
D(P, \mathcal{R}) = \sup_{R \in \mathcal{R}} \left\vert \frac{|P \cap R|}{N} - \frac{\mu (R)}{\mu (X)}\right\vert,
$$

where $\mu$ denotes the volume of $R$, $|\cdot|$ denotes the cardinality when applied to a finite set. (Definition taken from [this paper](http://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/338b/7fd3271b404b8e39a9b9f529278c9515f3ff.pdf) on motion planning.) Examples of [low-discrepancy sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence) (from Wikipedia) include [van der Corput sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput_sequence), [Halton sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halton_sequence), etc.

[EDIT 2] According to what I can find so far, a few papers (for example, [this one](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022314X8890025X/1-s2.0-0022314X8890025X-main.pdf?_tid=ed45fa40-1b4c-11e7-928a-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1491540467_315a92fa22b6e9bf691a3ab3be0066ef)) define a low-discrepancy sequence as one achieving a bound of the form
$$
\sup_{\mathcal{R}} |D(P, \mathcal{R}| \leq C_d (\log N)^d + \mathcal{O}\left((\log N)^{d - 1}\right),
$$
where $C_d$ is a constant.

Comment: What is the definition of low-descrepancy?

Comment: I have edited the question to include more details.

Comment: To be able to answer your question, it still requires the definition of "low" descrepancy. For example, how "low" the descrepancy exactly is?